# Каковы критерии аттестации StackOverflow на русском?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, аттестация

Хотелось бы увидеть полный и исчерпывающий список критериев, которым должен соответствовать этот сайт для завершения бета-стадии и аттестации.

По каждому критерию прошу установить  четкие и измеримые показатели.

Comment: +1, но сомневаюсь, что формальные критерии есть

Comment: @VladD тогда нужно их изобрести. А потом получить подтверждение их валидности.

Comment: @VladD может и правда, сами себе напишем? SO управляется сообществом, как-никак.

Comment: Это на самом деле можно, но примет ли наши критерии руководство большого SO?

Comment: @VladD если они будут соответствовать общим требованиям и только их уточнять и дополнять - то вполне вероятно. Посмотрите ссылки в описании метки аттестация. Там есть в общем виде.

Comment: @VladD например, там ни слова про локализацию. Мы должны выработать свои критерии качества локализации.

Comment: Кстати, да, локализация! Аттестация _обычно_ касается лишь англоязычных сайтов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Truly I tell you, whatever you bind on earth will be bound in heaven *Matthew 18:18*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Ответ коротко

К сожалению, должен вас огорчить. Как таковых критериев получения аттестации для Stack Overflow на русском нет.

### Обоснование

Давайте попробуем понять, почему (на мой взгляд).

#### Бета-версия сайта и аттестация

Во время *закрытой беты* сообщество, в узком кругу, создает минимальный набор вопросов, чтобы описать тематику будущего сайта и определяет самые значимые правила (например, какие вопросы можно задавать, а какие – нет). Тем самым «ядро энтузиастов» подготавливают площадку для более широкой публики. Важнейшем, по моему мнению, показателем закрытой беты является наличие заинтересованных участников, которые обладают достаточными знаниями и готовы посвятить себя нуждам сообщества – поддерживать минимальный уровень активности, задавая вопросы и отвечая на них друг другу.

Переход сайта в стадию *открытой беты* означает, что сообщество имеет лидеров, которые помогают другим участникам понять правила сайта, тематику и нормы общения. На стадии открой беты вокруг «ядра энтузиастов» должно собраться сообщество, само «ядро» должно пополниться новыми *знатоками* и *лидерами индустрии*, у сайта должны появиться *волонтеры*, помогающие поддерживать качество знаний и необходимый уровень общения (имеется в виду именно нормы общения, хотя активность, непременно, важна).

Думаю, наиболее критичной составляющей стадии *открытой беты* является не столько количество вопросов в день, сколько наличие Сообщества (именно с большой буквы), то есть знатоков, лидеров индустрии, волонтеров и ребят, интересующихся тематикой, и, конечно же, свода правил Сообщества.

Грубо говоря, получение аттестации для сайта означает, что сообщество готово «открыться миру»:

- сообщество имеет своих лидеров, волонтеров и энтузиастов;
- в сообществе публикуется стабильное количество вопросов и ответов (как минимум кривая на графике «сообщений во времени» должна быть неубывающая);
- сообщество поддерживает минимальный необходимый уровень качества публикуемых знаний (то есть управляющий сообществом от компании более не тратит времени на модерацию содержимого);
- сообщество активно управляет содержимым сайта (то есть голосует «за» и «против» сообщений, использует сигналы тревоги, *правильно* закрывает вопросы, вовремя реагирует на спам);
- сообщество активно обучает новых участников правилам использования сайта (то есть нормам общения, функционалу и способу его использования);
- сообщество активно следит за соблюдением всех совместно принятых правил (то есть не дает никому, включая «самых заслуженных» участников, грубить, отправлять в поисковик, публиковать ответы в комментариях и т. д.);
- сообщество активно на Мете (то есть улучшает существующие правила и восполняет их недостаток).

Именно об этом «говорят» цифры в [заявке на Зоне 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian).

#### Выше нет ответа на вопрос о том, что нам следует сделать для выхода из беты!

На самом деле есть. Для успешного завершения беты нам следует:

1. приглашать к участию коллег, которые могут помочь нам создавать больше качественных знаний<sup>*</sup>;
2. активней вовлекать существующее сообщество в процесс управления сообществом и содержимым;
3. улучшать качество знаний;
4. оттачивать правила сообщества.

<sup>*</sup> <sub>На мой взгляд, в первую очередь тех, кто заинтересован в изучении программирования. Достойных грамотных ребят, готовых помочь в трудную минуту коллеге в сообществе Stack Overflow на русском, достаточно, что не может не радовать, но я ни в коем случае не отговариваю вас от отправки приглашения знатоку: больше ответов – больше знаний.</sub>

К сожалению, сформулировать *четкие критерии* для выхода из беты для Stack Overflow на русском не получится, так как если бы мы руководствовались стандартными положениями, действующими для других бета-сайтов Сети, по всем показателям наше сообщество вышло бы из беты, еще будучи ХэшКод’ом несколько лет назад.

#### В завершение

Я провел много времени, обсуждая этот вопрос с коллегами, ответственными за аттестацию сайтов Сети. Насколько могу судить, они такого же мнения: Stack Overflow на русском – крепкое сообщество, на порядок превосходящее многие другие, прошедшие аттестацию. Мы можем вынести свою кандидатуру на рассмотрение, теоретически, в любой момент, но, как мне кажется, мы сперва должны решить свои внутренние задачи, описанные выше.

В моем представлении Stack Overflow на русском – это наше «окно» в мир знаний. От того, каким мы его создадим, напрямую зависит, какие ресурсы в будущем будут выделяться на русскоязычную часть Stack Exchange. Ведь если русскоязычному специалисту (программисту, математику, филологу и др.) более интересно подшучивание друг над другом, грубость и деструктивное самобичевание вместо конструктивной взаимной помощи и самоорганизации, зачем тогда ломиться в закрытую дверь? Я, например, уверен в обратном (именно поэтому и занимаюсь проектом вот уже почти 5 лет). Stack Overflow на русском – наш шанс показать остальным русскоязычным специалистам (и не только русскоязычным), что русскоязычное сообщество может самоорганизоваться, нести добродетель и знания в массы. Сделаем мы – сделают и другие.

Наше сообщество можно сравнить с реактивным самолетом: мы можем легко взлететь и быть полезны большому количеству людей, самое главное – не потерять тягу при взлете в случае слишком резкого подъема. Как только мы сами поймем, что готовы, компания нас непременно поддержит.

Comment: «ребят» — девчат бы тоже неплохо, а то почти нет их в сообществе.

Comment: Девчат не то что сообществе мало, их вообще в природе очень мало. Краснокнижный вид - айтишные девушки!