# Статистика отвеченных вопросов и актуальные задачи

Tags: обсуждение, аттестация

Здесь хранятся и обновляются ответы на следующие вопросы.

- Как наши дела на Area 51?
- Сколько вопросов отвечено?
- Какова скорость прироста количества отвеченных?
- Когда предположительно будет 85%?
- Как я могу принять участие в общем деле?

---

Для справки:

- [Наша страница на Area 51.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian)
- [Почему это важно?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/956/181472)
- [Как считается статистика на Area 51?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/807/181472)
- [Каковы общие критерии аттестации?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1287/181472)
- [Другая статистика сайта.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/875/181472)

Comment: обновилась статистика на area51 — у нас уже 80% отвеченных.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ага, тоже заметил.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin если вам есть что сказать по этому поводу - смело редактируйте мой ответ или пишите новый )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Статистика

[Исходный документ на Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1elyMkhpbKoP9Szf3mZ2O7BE6NGt58tGNb119xsjthwc/edit#gid=1810373476) (заполнять в нём следует только столбцы b,c,d. значения в столбцах e,f,g вычисляются полностью автоматически).

```
Дата        A       B       Всего   Отвеч.  Тек.  В среднем
2015-07-15  8205    8060    62040   74.62%        0.24%
2015-08-05  8139    8175    63197   75.03%  0.40%
2015-08-12  8160    8008    63585   75.41%  0.39% Когда 85%?
2015-08-19  8195    7734    64175   76.02%  0.61% 2016-05-19
2015-08-27  8275    7485    64864   76.54%  0.52%
2015-09-03  8253    7169    65039   77.13%  0.59%
2015-09-10  8154    7020    65481   77.67%  0.54%
2015-09-17  8022    6539    65885   78.74%  1.07%
2015-09-24  7992    6321    66261   79.24%  0.50%
2015-10-01  8031    6110    66859   79.69%  0.45%
2015-10-08  8118    5935    67420   80.00%  0.31%
2015-10-15  8144    5836    67859   80.24%  0.24%
2015-10-22  8159    5674    68334   80.60%  0.36%
2015-10-29  8162    5587    68882   80.88%  0.28%
2015-11-05  8261    5516    69475   81.01%  0.13%
2015-11-12  8324    5353    70052   81.32%  0.31%
2015-11-19  8425    5143    70670   81.64%  0.32%
2015-11-26  8509    4993    71334   81.91%  0.27%
2015-12-03  8600    4814    71914   82.19%  0.28%
2015-12-10  8782    4847    72629   82.07%  -0.11%
2015-12-17  8903    4729    73358   82.26%  0.18%
2015-12-24  8920    4558    74001   82.63%  0.37%
2015-12-31  8945    4372    74479   82.96%  0.33%
2016-01-07  9008    4206    74869   83.19%  0.23%
2016-01-14  9118    4065    75672   83.42%  0.23%
2016-01-21  9288    3992    76470   83.47%  0.05%
2016-01-28  9450    3863    77303   83.62%  0.14%
2016-02-04  9154    3549    78125   83.74%  0.12%
2016-02-11  9334    3455    78975   83.81%  0.07%
2016-02-18  9486    3536    79882   83.70%  -0.11%
2016-02-25  9703    3659    80798   83.46%  -0.24%
2016-03-03  9918    3529    81841   83.57%  0.11%
2016-03-10  10110   3428    82626   83.62%  0.05%
2016-03-17  10315   3348    83602   83.66%  0.04%
2016-03-24  10511   3249    84526   83.72%  0.06%
2016-03-31  10726   3137    85448   83.78%  0.06%
2016-04-07  10914   3035    86327   83.84%  0.07%
2016-04-14  11153   2945    87237   83.84%  0.00%
2016-04-21  11304   2842    88204   83.96%  0.12%
2016-04-28  11473   2572    89217   84.26%  0.30%
2016-05-05  11643   2253    90087   84.57%  0.32%
2016-05-12  11757   1943    91030   84.95%  0.38%
```

```
Дата        A       B       Всего   Отвеч.  Тек.
2016-05-19  11911   1644    92017   85.27%  0.32%
2016-05-26  12179   1335    93076   85.48%  0.21%
2016-06-02  12369   1167    93858   85.58%  0.10%
2016-06-09  12538   820     94840   85.92%  0.34%
2016-06-16  12664   547     95722   86.20%  0.28%
2016-06-23  12791   350     96570   86.39%  0.19%
2016-06-30  12933   150     97436   86.57%  0.18%
2016-07-07  13105   132     98363   86.54%  -0.03%
2016-07-14  13254   79      99308   86.57%  0.03%
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Каковы актуальные задачи?

Есть группа B (есть ответы, но не приняты и без голосов) , в которой могут быть хорошие, но неоцененные ответы. В первую очередь нужно разбирать эту группу:

1. [Откройте поисковый запрос по группе B.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20isanswered%3ano%20answers%3a1..%20hasaccepted%3ano%20closed%3Ano)
2. Можно добавить к поиску свои любимые метки: [`intags:mine`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3Aquestion%20isanswered%3Ano%20answers%3A1..%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20closed%3Ano%20intags%3Amine)
3. Просмотрите сколько-нибудь вопросов, и в каждом:

   - Если знаете ответ — ответьте<sup>1</sup>.
   - Если дан хороший ответ — проголосуйте за ответ.
   - Если ответ дан в комментарии — скопируйте его в ответ и опубликуйте. Если вы при этом ничего не добавляете к ответу, то хорошим тоном считается сделать его общим.
   - Если ответа нет, но вопрос хороший — проголосуйте за вопрос.
   - Если вопрос безнадёжен (непонятен), не по теме сайта или проблема невоспроизводима — используйте соответствующую отметку тревоги. *Отмечайте только те вопросы без ответов, которые бы были удалены даже если бы они были заданы сегодня.*

<sup>1: [Нужно ли отвечать на вопросы, заданные достаточно давно?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/156/181472)</sup>

### Как считается статистика, кратко:

- Группа A: вопросы, не имеющие ответов вообще. [`is:question isanswered:no answers:0 closed:no`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20isanswered%3Ano%20answers%3A0%20closed%3Ano)
- Группа B: вопросы, не имеющие ни принятого ответа, ни ответа с положительной суммой голосов. [`is:question isanswered:no answers:1.. hasaccepted:no closed:no`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20isanswered%3ano%20answers%3a1..%20hasaccepted%3ano%20closed%3Ano)
- Общее количество вопросов на сайте ∑:  [`is:question`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20is%3Aquestion)

Нужно, чтобы `(A + B ) / ∑ ≤ 0.15`.

### 2016-01-30

Оказалось, что запросы были не совсем верны: для групп A и B нужно добавить ещё `closed:no`. Тогда посчёт процента отвеченных вопросов [совпадает](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uEwqqSpfKx_j6p0qwwLRoe_-XjjrxZGALDFzbiqFdZg/edit?usp=sharing) с данными на странице [статистики сайтов](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). Чтобы не было скачка в столбце `Тек.`, имеющаяся на данный момент разница в 0.84% добавлена ко всем числам в столбце `Отвеч.` в строках с `2015-07-15` по `2016-01-28` (а из числа в столбце `Тек.` за `2015-02-04` пришлось ту же разницу вычесть ввиду особенностей формулы в этом столбце).

Comment: Если из группы А (вопросы без ответов, сейчас 8159) удалить 4250 вопросов (а до 2015 года наверняка есть такое количество без голосов ЗА), то как раз получится 85% отвеченных. / Подумайте и обсудите.

Comment: Для обсуждения вопроса создан специальный [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35021/discussion-on-answer-by-nick-volynkin-----).

Comment: А группа `A` (вопросы совсем без ответов) все растет и растет...

Comment: если никто не подхватит эстафету по группе бэ, то смысл ведения статистики, по-моему, теряется: на основе двух прецедентов я делаю вывод, что усилия всего одного человека позволяют менять тенденцию изменения процента отвеченных с минуса на плюс. и после того как этот человек перестал заниматься группой бэ, мы уходим в «минуса».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin подумаю насчет нового массового призыва. ) человек - это вы?

Comment: Хочу в очередной раз обратить внимание на рост группы А (общее количество вопросов вообще без ответа). Если в октябре 15-го года (когда этот процесс начался) таких было 11% (за 2 недели), то за последние 2 надели их уже 18% от всех заданных вопросов. Т.е. по сути **каждый пятый** вопрос остается без ответа.

Comment: @avp за последние недели всегда больше неотвеченных - не все получают ответ сразу. Или вы точно помните именно за две недели статистику?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я на нее в таблице выше только что смотрел. Или эта таблица не актуальна? (правильной считается только последняя строка?)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, вот уже и перевалили за 85%. пора ставить новые цели. p.s. куда смотрит avp — не понятно: группа «а» весь период наблюдения крутится вокруг 12-13% от общего количества вопросов.

Comment: За последнюю неделю группа А несколько улучшилась -- `(11911 - 11757) / (92017-91030) = 15.6%` Т.е. я смотрю на ее долю во вновь заданных вопросах. А в целом, сейчас 12.9% (в самом начале наблюдений 13.2%, в сердине было и 12.0%)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin очень благодарен вам за обновление информации. Давайте как-нибудь в чате встретимся и обсудим, какой сейчас приоритетный вектор работы, кого и как к нему стоит привлекать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, 1. комната для этого ответа «заморожена». 2. «для красоты» стоило бы «добить» группу b, с чем я один не справлюсь ввиду того, что там слишком много моих (единственных) ответов. 3. дальше, естественно, надо «разгребать» группу a, но конструктивных предложений по поводу того, кого и как к этому следует привлекать, у меня, увы, нет.