# Ответ с тремя (!) голосами не считается «полноценным» ответом

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, поиск

При поиске вопросов, имеющих ответы, ни один из которых не принят и не «проголосован» (т. н. группа b, упомянутая в [ответе на вопрос «Статистика отвеченных вопросов и актуальные задачи»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1340/178576)), по поисковому запросу [is:question isanswered:no answers:1.. hasaccepted:no closed:no](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20isanswered%3ano%20answers%3a1..%20hasaccepted%3ano%20closed%3ano), примерно на странице (в текущий момент, при отображении 15 сообщений на страницу) 174, встречается вопрос, ответ на который [отмечен **тремя** «положительными» голосами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455398/178576).

Но этот вопрос всё равно остаётся «неотвеченным»!

В [timeline-е](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/455398/timeline) видно, что первый «голос» ответ «заработал» ещё в прошлом году (последний голос — мой, от 16 апреля, и он тоже не «помог»).

Может быть, этот сбой как-то связан с (непонятным мне) пунктом в timeline:

> сообщение объединено с другим (конечным)

---

Чтобы убедиться, что вопрос всё ещё присутствует в поисковом запросе с теми же параметрами, добавьте к запросу слова из заголовка: [is:question isanswered:no answers:1.. hasaccepted:no closed:no реализация text select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ano+answers%3A1..+hasaccepted%3Ano+closed%3Ano+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+text+select) — отобразится именно этот вопрос.

Comment: @Discord, спасибо за весьма ценные исправления. // нет ли в ваших планах [очереди проверок, которой так необходима крепкая модераторская рука](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)?

Comment: мне кажется _hasaccepted_ в запросе говорит что ищет вопросы у которых есть _принятый_ ответ, а в примере из вопроса - ответ с 3 голосами не принят

Comment: @Grundy, совершенно верно, **и** *непринятые* **и** вопросы **и** «неотвеченные» **и** с количеством ответов больше нуля **и** незакрытые: все эти разделённые пробелом параметры объединяются логическим **и**. вопрос, о котором я пишу, по своим (известным мне) параметрам **не** должен попадать в результаты запроса.

Comment: Странно, у меня там всего 58 страниц.

Comment: а вы точно человек? просмотреть 174 страницы вопросов!!! о_О

Comment: @NickVolynkin, у меня выбрано отображать по 15 сообщений на страницу. потому страниц больше

Comment: @Grundy, я с конца списка работаю. отсортированного по дате. сейчас приходится пропускать уже 20 страниц с конца — там либо только заминусованные ответы, либо мои, за которые я, понятно, проголосовать не могу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, все равно ужас :-)

Comment: @Grundy, я уже с пол-года работаю над сокращением этой «группы b». примерно пять тысяч голосов (движок даёт проголосовать только за 30 ответов в день) — это «немного больше», чем 20 страниц по 15 сообщений, но ничего ужасного в этом нет: просто ежедневная рутина.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, мне все-таки кажется используется бот :-) меня бы не хватило каждый день по 30 ответов в день :)

Comment: @Grundy, если б кто-то написал такого бота, я бы был не против (сам не потяну). вот только как этот бот будет определять, что, например, вопрос следует закрыть, или выбирать, за какой из ответов проголосовать, если их больше одного?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ИИ - нейронные сети всякие с обучалками :-)

Comment: @Grundy, ну, пока приходится обходиться «естественным».

Comment: Да уж, ээээх. Котлетка :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С этим вопросом был объединен другой: [Как вывести изображение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455388/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Возможно, поисковой движок находит тот вопрос, но вместо него показывает этот. Думаю, это можно считать багом.

Comment: *находит тот* — по-моему, не подходит такая причина. последняя ссылка в вопросе (добавлены ключевые слова из заголовка), по идее, не должна «находить» вопрос «как вывести изображение?».

Answer (score 2):

[В соответствии со справкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching),

`isanswered:no` - выполняет поиск вопросов без ответов отмеченных как принятый или ответов с положительной оценкой.

В данном случае проверяются два условия:

1. У вопроса нет ответа помеченного как принятый
2. У принятого ответа **не** положительный рейтинг

Если выполняется хотя бы одно условие, то вопрос считается подходящим фильтру.

Так как у вопроса из примера ответ не принят - он подходит.

Также пример, когда у ответа *есть* принятый ответ, но который не имеет положительный рейтинг:

фильтр: [is:question isanswered:no Проблемы с .properties](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20isanswered%3Ano%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D1%81%20.properties)
вопрос: [Проблемы с .properties](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/119606/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-properties)

[В английской версии справки](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) говорится только о рейтинге, но работает так же

фильтр: [is:question isanswered:no answers:1..  closed:no Pre- or post-process roxygen snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20isanswered%3Ano%20answers%3A1..%20%20closed%3Ano%20Pre-%20or%20post-process%20roxygen%20snippets)
вопрос: [Q: Pre- or post-process roxygen snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540321/pre-or-post-process-roxygen-snippets)

А так же ссылка по теме: [OK, Now Define "Answered"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/)

Comment: Там не так написано. `isanswered:. yes, true или 1 - выполняет поиск вопросов содержащих как минимум один ответ отмеченный как принятый или с положительной оценкой;`

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ага, и прям за этим: `no, false, 0 - выполняет поиск вопросов без ответов отмеченных как принятый или ответов с положительной оценкой.`

Comment: Перечитайте ваши два условия. Они некорректны. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, но именно так они работают :-) Я думаю тут либо трудности перевода, либо ошибка в справке

Comment: Если у принятого ответа положительный рейтинг, то вопрос считается `isanswered:no`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет, если у вопроса ответ принят, но рейтинг не положительный. Да вижу где неточность :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так лучше?

Comment: Да, так лучше. )